# Entity framework tracking wrong model object after helper method

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

Below is some basic code that's a part of our `Create` controller method. If a certain checkbox is selected, we want to create a copy of the `agenttransmission` object we are currently creating, with a couple fields altered.

When the program goes into the helper method, it creates the `sub` record without incident, however for some reason, when the program finishes and comes back to the `Create` method, the model object `agenttransmission` becomes the `sub` model object. All value, including the `PK` are suddenly pressent in the `agenttransmission` object.

Not sure how this is happening since there is a `string` return value on the helper method and no fields are touched on the `agenttransmission` record.

**Create method**

```
//Create substat if requested
if (agenttransmission.OverrideId)
{
    status += ". " + CreateSubStat(agenttransmission);
}
```

**Helper method**

```
    public string CreateSubStat(AgentTransmission master)
    {
        string msg = string.Empty;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (AgentResourcesEntities tempDb = new AgentResourcesEntities())
            {
                try
                {
                    //Check to see if substat already exists
                    var check = (from a in db.AgentTransmission
                                 where a.ParentId == master.ID && a.RecordStatus.Equals("P")
                                 select a).ToList();

                    if (check.Count > 0) return string.Empty;

                    //If not add dependent record
                    AgentTransmission sub = master;
                    sub.OverrideId = false;
                    sub.DRMCompanyId = string.Empty;
                    sub.CONCode = "00";
                    sub.RecordStatus = "P";
                    sub.ParentId = master.ID;
                    sub.ID = 0;
                    sub.IsSubstat = true;
                    sub.SendToDynamicsOptions = "N";
                    sub.SendToNMF = false;

                    //Remove blanks from ClearinghousePartners list
                    sub.ClearinghousePartners.RemoveAll(
                        x =>
                        string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.ClearingHouseName) &&
                        string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.TradingPartnerName) && x.StartDate == null);

                    sub.AgentRelationshipCodes.RemoveAll(
                        x =>
                        string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.RelationshipId) &&
                        !x.EffectiveDate.HasValue && x.Id == 0);

                    foreach (var item in sub.AgentRelationshipCodes)
                    {
                        item.LastChangeDate = DateTime.Now;
                        item.LastChangeId = SecurityRules.GetUserName(User);
                        item.AgentTransmission = sub;
                        item.AgtTableId = sub.ID;
                    }

                    foreach (var item in sub.ClearinghousePartners)
                    {
                        item.AgentTransmission = sub;
                        item.AgtTransId = sub.ID;
                    }

                    db.AgentTransmission.Add(sub);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    msg = "Substat saved with status of 'Dependent'.";
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
                {
                    msg = "Error creating substat. IT has been informed and will respond shortly.";
                    SendEmail.ErrorMail(dbEx.Message, SecurityRules.GetUserName(User));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    msg = "Error creating substat. IT has been informed and will respond shortly.";
                    SendEmail.ErrorMail(ex, SecurityRules.GetUserName(User));
                }
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            //Invalid ModelState error handling
            string messages = string.Join("; ", ModelState.Values
                                                          .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
                                                          .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
            SendEmail.ErrorMail("Error Creating Substat: " + messages, SecurityRules.GetUserName(User));
            msg = "Error creating substat. IT has been informed and will respond shortly.";
        }

        return msg;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line...

```
AgentTransmission sub = master;
```

...doesn't copy `master` to `sub`, but *assigns* it to `sub`, because `AgentTransmission` is a reference type. So everything you do to `sub` you do to `master`.

You either must clone `master` to `sub` (create a new object and copy its properties), or re-fetch the master object from the database after the `CreateSubStat` call.